# Cannot load Partial Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I am trying to render partials from my layouts but it's not working(only the hello text is displayed). The partials are located in the layouts folder.

```
/layouts/application.html.erb
<body>
    <%= render partial: "layouts/header" %>

    <%= yield %>

    <%= render partial: "layouts/footer" %>
  </body>
```

```
/layouts/_header.html.erb
<h1>Header</h1>
```

```
/layouts/_footer.html.erb
<h1>Footer</h1>
```

```
public/index.html.erb
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: What's the error? I fear "it's not working" is not enough to help

Comment: The partials are not loading

Comment: I suspect the header file in the layouts folder is missing an underscore. It should be named `_header.html.erb`. That's really the only reason I can think of why this wouldn't be working, unless you're missing a file called `header.html.erb` completely. Same format should be applied to the footer file of course.

Comment: @scilence I did name it with the underscore and it's not working

Comment: And you're not getting an error message? What happens if you view the source of the page? Are you seeing the code in the source that would be loaded from the partials?

Comment: No error message and the partials are not displaying when I view the source code of the page in the browser. I really don't understand what's happening

Comment: There's not enough information here to make a determination as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried just with "render", not with "render partial:"?, Also, it is a good practice to use just single quotes when you are not using string interpolation or any other special characters inside your strings

Comment: Since your partials are in the same directory as where you’re calling them from, you should be able to call `<%= render ‘header’ %>` and `<%= render ‘footer’ %>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render 'header' %>.
```

I removed the "partial" and it now works

Answer (score -1):

Try with  `<%= render 'shared/header' %>` where all your partials should be inside the **shared** folder `views/shared`